# jquery load not getting inside html

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, but when I alert the **isactive**, it is always showing me empty

```
var isaction = $("#bottom_content").get('cookiedata.cfm?answer=1&new=' + Math.random());
alert(isaction.html());
if ($.trim(isaction) == 'Empty') {
    $("#bottom_content").hide('5000').load('cookiedata.cfm?new=' + Math.random());
} else {
    $("#bottom_content").show('5000').load('cookiedata.cfm?new=' + Math.random());
}
```

The CFM file is returning me the Empty or Exists HTML, but on that basis I am trying to hide the contents, but alert is always empty.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct get method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$.get('cookiedata.cfm?answer=1&new=' + Math.random(), function(data){
    if (!data.length) {
        $("#bottom_content").hide('5000').load('cookiedata.cfm?new=' + Math.random());
    } else {
        $("#bottom_content").html(data);
        $("#bottom_content").show('5000').load('cookiedata.cfm?new=' + Math.random());
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not working, and i added alert after the function(data), but i am not getting alert, isn;t using load is good

Comment: You can try `load` as well but what not working and check the browser console for errors.